# Probability Joint PDF and Joint CDF

Tags: probability

Let R be the bounded region between y = x and y = x². A point (X, Y) is chosen uniformly at random from the region R. Please find the joint PDF and the joint CDF of X and Y.

I believed that the joint PDF formula is 1 / area(R) if (X, Y) is inside the region R. However, since area(R) is 1/6, then the PDF becomes 6(?) It confuses me.

Can someone help me please...

Comment: The pdf is indeed $f(x, y) = 6$. What is it that confuses you? Is it the fact that the value you get for the PDF is greater than $1$? Or is it that the question asks for a PDF for two random variables? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: Okay thanks, I just got confused because the PDF is greater than 1. Thanks a lot

Comment: By the way, what are the bounds of the integrals for finding the CDF? Is it 0 to x for dx, and x² to y for dy?

Comment: No.  How can $x$ range from $0$ to $x$?  That is  $0\leqslant x\leqslant x$

Comment: Plot the curves, notice where they intersect, and which is lower.  It is $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ and $x^2\leqslant y\leqslant x$. $$\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leqslant x^2\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}\\\text{or}\\\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant\surd y\leqslant 1\}$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to get the joint CDF

Comment: It's ok for a probability density function to be greater than $1$. It must however have an integral evaluating to $1$. Maybe you are confusing the probability **density** function with the probability **mass** function which is used for discrete random variables and since it tells you 'what is the probability for each value' it can't be greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.   The function (including its support) is: $$f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)= 6\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x^2\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant 1}$$

There is no issue with the magnitude.   Since it is a probability *density*, rather than *mass*, function it may be greater than one.   You just need to ensure the total probability mass equals one.

$$\int_0^1\int^x_{x^2} 6 ~\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x= 6{\bigl[\tfrac 12x^2-\tfrac 13x^3\bigr]}_{x=0}^{x=1}=1$$